# Is there a way to print multiple bar codes for each entry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode, barcode-printing, jquery-barcode

I am attempting to print the isbn bar code, title, author, published date and if it exists the alternate isbn.  The code below works great with just one isbn, but when I try to add another it will not print the second bar code.  Here is what I have:

```
    sku = data.sku;
    isbn = data.isbn;
    author = data.author;
    alt = data.alt;
    pub_date = data.pubDate;
    for (x=0;x<data.isbn.length;x++)
    {
        title = data.title[x];
        title = title.substring(0,20);

        first += '$("#'+indexGlobal+'").barcode("'+isbn[x]+'", "codabar",{barHeight:40, fontSize:30, output:"bmp"});';
        second += '<div class="wrapper"><div id="'+indexGlobal+'"></div><div class="fullSKU">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp '+isbn[x]+
        '</div><br /><div class="title">'+author[x]+
                '</div><br/><div class="title">'+title+'</div><br /><div class="title">'+pub_date[x]+
        '</div><br /><br /><br />';

        indexGlobal++; 

                }
```

I have tried just entering a third line( and declaring the var indexGlobal2 at the top):

```
third += '$("#'+indexGlobal2+'").barcode("'+alt[x]+'", "codabar",{barHeight:40, fontSize:30, output:"bmp"});';
```

which did not work at all.  I have also tried adjusting the height of the wrapper to allow for more room, and that did nothing either.
Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: The first += line prints out the bar code, the second+= prints out the isbn number, author, title and published date.  I need a third line to print out the alternate isbn number.

Comment: what barcode library are you using?

Comment: Why is this question tagged PHP?

Comment: I removed that tag. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: what's the purpose of the `first` string? also: don't use globals, please, they are like asbestos: seems like a quick and effective solution to a problem, but are equally hard to get rid of, plus: they spread like cancer and kill your script all together

Comment: Shouldn't it be +isbn[x]+ in your third+= line ?

Comment: Where is indexGlobal defined?

Comment: The question is rather vague.  But my guess is that it has to do with how you are defining the `data` variable.  It looks like it is a javascript object.  Also it depends what your "keys" are for this object.  You are probably overwriting the first isbn with the second one.  So if your for loop you are only displaying the second isbn.

Comment: sorry this is code that I have inherited, what would you rec. I use? @Daniel,I am not sure, it was all in place when I was assigned the project to add the additional bar code.

Comment: Jerska, I need to print the alternate isbn, which is why I have it as alt[x]

Comment: @DanielA.White After searching around a bit, it appears that we are using jquery-barcode.js.